# REST API Design per entity

Tags: rest, api

Should we have one REST API endpoint per entity? 
For example, We have Employee and he has office address, personal address, some other address. When consumers request for employee details, should we just return "firstName,lastName and IDs of address" and consumer fire another query for address objects. How do we chose which approach and what are the guidelines that will help making such decision.

Comment: What is your requirement. What is the expected output. Decide these first. Then move on to the expected performance(SLA,Availiability) . Then take decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should we have one REST API endpoint per entity?

There are no universal rules in the world. Programming is only half a science. It's an art for another half. You decide what to choose. And we cannot advise you without knowning your context.

> For example, We have Employee and he has office address, personal
>   address, some other address. When consumers request for employee
>   details, should we just return "firstName,lastName and IDs of address"
>   and consumer fire another query for address objects. How do we chose
>   which approach and what are the guidelines that will help making such
>   decision.

Try to look at how it's implemented in [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/). In a few words: just use a query parameter that represents a list of fields/dependent objects, that need to be included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

> Should we have one REST API endpoint per entity?

"The RESTful interface will typically have many many many more resources than you will have domain objects in your core domain model." -- Jim Webber (2011)

> When consumers request for employee details, should we just return "firstName,lastName and IDs of address" and consumer fire another query for address objects. How do we chose which approach and what are the guidelines that will help making such decision.

It's useful to keep in mind how the Web is supposed to work.  Fielding describes many of the problems the web architecture was designed to solve in [chapter 4 of his thesis](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/web_arch_domain.htm#sec_4_1_3):

> Hypermedia is defined by the presence of application control information embedded within, or as a layer above, the presentation of information. Distributed hypermedia allows the presentation and control information to be stored at remote locations. By its nature, user actions within a distributed hypermedia system require the transfer of large amounts of data from where the data is stored to where it is used. Thus, the Web architecture must be designed for large-grain data transfer.

In other words, *caching* is a significant concern, if you are going to be operating at web scale.

If employee details are stable, then throwing all of them into one long lived document is great - that document can serve many requests, for a long time.  On the other hand, any clients that are working from a cached copy of the document aren't seeing the latest changes -- volatile data will typically want to have different caching rules from stable data.

Fine grain resources tend to be easier for editing - in HTTP, PUT replaces the state of a resource.  Smaller resources mean less data for the client to keep track of, and less chance of collision with other edits.